# Redux - Dispatching Action (onClick Event)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am simply trying to `connect()` my `LoginPage (component)` to my `Redux Store` and `dispatch` in action via a `onClick (event)`. When I `console.log(this.props)` my dispatch handler `login()` isn't in the component's props.

**GitHub Repo** -- https://github.com/jdavis-software/demo.git

**Question:** Why isn't my `Redux Store` either `connection` or `dispatching` the actions?

**LoginPage:**

```js
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {  connect } from 'react-redux';

export class LoginPage extends Component<any> {
    render(){
        console.log('props doesnt have contain - login(): ', this.props)
        return (<button onClick={ () => '' }>Login</button>)
    }
}

const mapProps = state => ({ user: state.user })

const dispatchProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        login: () => dispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGGED_IN', payload: true})
    } 
}

export default connect(mapProps,dispatchProps)(LoginPage)
```

**Redux Configuration:**

```js
import { IStore, IUser } from '@interfaces';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
// reducers
import userReducer from './user.reducer';

// define the intial global store state
const initialState:IStore = {
    user: {
        isAuthenticated: false
    }
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({user: userReducer}) 

export default createStore(appReducer,initialState);
```

**User Reducer:**

```js
// initial state
const initalState:IUser = {
    isAuthenticated: false
}

// reducer
const userReducer = (state:IUser = initalState, { type, payload}: IPayload): IUser => {
    console.log('user reducer start', state)
    switch (type) {
        case 'USER_LOGGED_IN':
            state = { ...state, isAuthenticated: payload }
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
    return state;
};
export default userReducer;
```

**Root Page:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// styles
import './index.scss';
// pages
import { App } from '@pages';
// store
import store from './core/store/store';

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: What is your redux-store configuration?

Comment: I'd look at hooks too

Comment: @TasosBu just added it

Comment: @JamieHutber yeah I've been looking at that just trying to get this to work before I rewire everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code on git repository. I found out that you're exporting the named export

```
export class LoginPage
```

and the default export,

```
export default connect(mapProps,dispatchProps)(LoginPage)
```

But when you're accessing it, you're accessing it as

```
import { /*Other components*/ , LoginPage } from '@pages'
```

So it is actually taking the named exported component which is not connected to store.

I suggest you to import as

```
import LoginPage , { /*Other components*/ } from '@pages'
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! think I was coding for to long 

Answer (score 1):

Return statements are missing in the properties of connect.

```
const mapProps = state => { return {user: state.user} }

const dispatchProps = (dispatch) => { 
  return {
    login: () => dispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGGED_IN', payload: true})
   }
}

export default connect(mapProps,dispatchProps)(LoginPage)
```

Updated:
Please check [Redux-dispatch](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-kirch-tueiz?file=/src/store.js)

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference the `arrow` function default returns, but just for piece of mind I tried it out and didn't change anything.

Comment: yes, but as you had added curly braces that won't make sense either you have to add return or you need to enclose by function brackets. The store which you have created should be available to LoginPage component. Can you paste that code too?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {  connect } from 'react-redux';

export class LoginPage extends Component<any> {
    render(){
        console.log('props doesnt contain - login(): ', this.props)
        return (
            <button onClick={ this.props.login }>Login</button>
        )
    }
}

const mapProps = state => ({ user: state.user })

const dispatchProps = (dispatch) => ({ 
    login: () => dispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGGED_IN', payload: true})
})

export default connect(mapProps,dispatchProps)(LoginPage)
```

to return an object with `Arrow Functions` you need to wrap your {} with ()

Comment: Yeah I tried that for piece of mind and didn't change anything.